# Issues with jlabel/button formatting

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

The category labels 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 don't seem to align with row I'm assigning them to. I don't understand where the problem is; the x value is equal. If someone could lead me in the right direction, that would be really great.

Here's my code

```
public class GovernmentJepordyGame {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jepordy");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1300,900);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        /*JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome to government jepordy.");*/
        JLabel catagoryOne = new JLabel("Catagory 1");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(catagoryOne, c); 
        JButton button500A = new JButton("500");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(65, 65, 65, 65); 
        panel.add(button500A, c);       
        JButton button400A = new JButton("400");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(button400A, c);
        JButton button300A = new JButton("300");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(button300A, c);
        JButton button200A = new JButton("200");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(button200A, c);
        JButton button100A = new JButton("100");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(button100A, c);

        JLabel catagoryTwo = new JLabel("Catagory 2");
        c.gridx = -1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(catagoryTwo, c); 
        JButton button500B = new JButton("500");
        c.gridx = -1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(65, 65, 65, 65); 
        panel.add(button500B, c);       
        JButton button400B = new JButton("400");
        c.gridx = -1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(button400B, c);
        JButton button300B = new JButton("300");
        c.gridx = -1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(button300B, c);
        JButton button200B = new JButton("200");
        c.gridx = -1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(button200B, c);
        JButton button100B = new JButton("100");
        c.gridx = -1;
        c.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(button100B, c);

        JLabel catagoryThree = new JLabel("Catagory 3");
        c.gridx = -2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(catagoryThree);
        JButton button500C = new JButton("500");
        c.gridx = -2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(65, 65, 65, 65); 
        panel.add(button500C, c);       
        JButton button400C = new JButton("400");
        c.gridx = -2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(button400C, c);
        JButton button300C = new JButton("300");
        c.gridx = -2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(button300C, c);
        JButton button200C = new JButton("200");
        c.gridx = -2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(button200C, c);
        JButton button100C = new JButton("100");
        c.gridx = -2;
        c.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(button100C, c);

        JLabel catagoryFour = new JLabel("Catagory 4");
        c.gridx = -3;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(catagoryFour);
        JButton button500D = new JButton("500");
        c.gridx = -3;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(65, 65, 65, 65); 
        panel.add(button500D, c);       
        JButton button400D = new JButton("400");
        c.gridx = -3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(button400D, c);
        JButton button300D = new JButton("300");
        c.gridx = -3;
        c.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(button300D, c);
        JButton button200D = new JButton("200");
        c.gridx = -3;
        c.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(button200D, c);
        JButton button100D = new JButton("100");
        c.gridx = -3;
        c.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(button100D, c);

        JLabel catagoryFive = new JLabel("Catagory 5");
        c.gridx = -4;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(catagoryFive);
        JButton button500E = new JButton("500");
        c.gridx = -4;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(65, 65, 65, 65); 
        panel.add(button500E, c);       
        JButton button400E = new JButton("400");
        c.gridx = -4;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(button400E, c);
        JButton button300E = new JButton("300");
        c.gridx = -4;
        c.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(button300E, c);
        JButton button200E = new JButton("200");
        c.gridx = -4;
        c.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(button200E, c);
        JButton button100E = new JButton("100");
        c.gridx = -4;
        c.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(button100E, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"..the x value is equal.."*  x represents the column, not the row!

Comment: `c.gridx = -1;` is not a valid value for `gridx`

Comment: BTW - 'jepordy' is spelled 'jeopardy'..

Answer (score 1):

The `gridx` should be a positive value, something like...

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jepordy");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    c.gridx = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {

        c.gridy = 0;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Catagory " + index);
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        panel.add(label, c);
        c.insets = new Insets(65, 65, 65, 65);
        for (int cat = 1; cat < 6; cat++) {
            c.gridy++;
            panel.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(cat * 100)), c);
        }

        c.gridx++;
    }
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1300, 900);
```

for instance...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting x and y mixed up. The top left corner of your screen is 0,0. As you move to the right, x increases, as you move down, y increases. So assigning a (-) value to your x coordinate system is not necessary, it will move likely start moving your buttons off screen to the left. Every button, try increasing the x grid value, instead of the y, and you should get your desired results.

gridx = 10....gridx = 20.. and so on.

Even better, implement some sort of loop to iterate through each button and increase the x values upon each iterate.

Or, look into flowlayout managers, they handle this automatically.